# Adding config file in docker run command

Tags: docker

This docker command works as expected:

```
docker run -i -t -p 7778:8888 continuumio/miniconda3 /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser --allow-root"
```

It starts miniconda with python 3 version installed. The problem is that it generates a random password to access jupyter when I go to ...

http://somesite.com:7778

And there is no way to change the password. The only way is to create or update the config file jupyter_notebook_config.py found in home directory (sub-folder: ~/.jupyter)
How do I save this file on host and mount it using -v parameter?

I can do this manually if I follow these 3 steps:

1) Login to ipython docker container

```
docker exec -it 6cbc bash
```

2) Run the following command...

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

3) Copy the config file to the container using a command something like this...

```
docker cp ipython_kernel_config.py  6cbc8d829e4a:/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

I am looking for a way to merge these 3 steps into the docker run command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried adding a volume mount to the run command?

Something like this.

```
docker run -i -t -v /tmp/.jupyter:/.jupyter/ -p 7778:8888 continuumio/miniconda3 /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser --allow-root"
```

This assumes you have a `/tmp/.jupyter` directory, and feel free to change to something else.

Also, this is a messy command, any reason why you don't create your own image using a Dockerfile? Here is a rough example, haven't tested so probably some typos and syntax errors, you but get the idea.

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet
RUN mkdir /opt/notebooks
# COPY in your custom config 
COPY ipython_kernel_config.py /.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
EXPOSE 8888
# RUN the notebook
CMD ["/opt/conda/bin/jupyter", "notebook", "--notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks", "--ip='*'", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--allow-root"]
```

To build and run you would do something like this.

```
docker build -t myminiconda3 .
docker run -it -p 7778:8888 myminiconda3
```

you can even mount in your local files if you want.

```
docker run -it -v `pwd`:/mycode -p 7778:8888 myminiconda3
```

And even run as a daemon

```
docker run -d -v `pwd`:/mycode -p 7778:8888 myminiconda3
```